# ng-show directive - inconsistent behavior

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement a versioning system for my application and I've tied one of the DOM elements that display the versions to the ng-show directive.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" ng-show="showVersionsTable()" ng-click="openVersionsTable()">[Manage]</a>
```

The controller code looks like this

```
showVersionsTable: function() { 
  if($scope.VersionsFilter.length >1 || $scope.VersionNumber >1 )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

The manage link used to come up fine if there are more than one versions for a document but since I've upgraded to angular 1.2.0, whenever I create a new document, which automatically creates one version for it, and do subsequent edits on the same document, creating more than one versions, the Manage link fails to appear.
I've debugged through the showVersionsTable code and after the subsequent edits, the scope variables are updated and showVersionsTable is invoked multiple times and everytime it returns true too but then UI does not get updated. Manage still remains hidden and after that, even if I try to navigate to another document with more than one versions on it, Manage still remains invisible though showVersionsTable returns true. This never happens if I start with editing a preexisting document. If I reload the page, the visibility of manage for each document becomes proper again. 
I'm not sure whether this has anything to do with the angular update. What would be the issue?. Thanks in advance.
PS: I've reproduced the code from memory so please forgive any syntactical errors.

Comment: Does it work if you place expression dirctely in directive quotes like ng-show="Versions.filter.length > 1 || VersionNumber > 1"

Comment: The culprit may not be in your evaluation (showVersionsTable method) but in the way you are changing those properties in your scope. Hard to tell without seeing the other parts of your application. How/when are you changing `VersionsFilter` and `VersionNumber`?

Comment: On a successful save, the VersionNumber gets set and the VersionsFilter gets initialized with the version objects and the initialization part is happening fine and the showVersionsTable code gets invoked after that too with both the VersionNumber and VersionsFilter.length  > 1. One thing I've noticed is, even if I replace the showVersionsTable code with just a return true, and no conditions, the problem still exists for the flow I've described.

Comment: @AngularAddict I'll try that out but its essentially the same thing right?

Comment: @AngularAddict it doesn't help if I put the condition directly without the function. Even if I put true directly for ng-show it still does not work.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle/plunk for this?

Comment: Does 1+1==2 as expression make your element visible?